# How to open Android app from a link without asking user to select between browser or app the first time

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have managed to get App Linking working for Android where it opens the app when opening the specified url.

I am opening the url `https://fir-trial-66e3f.web.app/stripesub`

However it asks me whether I want to use the app or google chrome to open the link, with the options "JUST ONCE" or "ALWAYS".

**I want it to automatically open in the app the first time and to not ask the user.**

I have tried following the instructions here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34360396/10222449) by adding `android:autoVerify="true"` and I have verified my website. 
I did not need to upload the json file as it verified it automatically as I use the same google account as the firebase project owner.
**However it still asks the same question.**

I am using an Ionic app with Capacitor, however I don't think that is related to the issue.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="fir-trial-66e3f.web.app"
                    android:pathPrefix="/stripesub" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Resources I used:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: I figured this out.  Even though it auto verified me I still needed to generate the json file from within Android studio and copy to: https://myurl/.well-known/assetlinks.json.  I also needed to copy and paste it into notepad due to end of line issue (I think) and I put a carriage return at the end of the json or it wasn't working.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549183/10222449  If anyone is interested let me know and I will put up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it auto verified me at search.google.com I still needed to generate the json file from within Android studio and copy to: myurl/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

To do this go to Android Studio -> Tools -> App Links Asssistant -> Step 3 Associate Website

I also needed to copy and paste it into notepad due to end of line issue (I think) and I put a carriage return at the end of the json or it wasn't working.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549183/669586