# Custom file extension open inside a specific app

Tags: android, react-native

Let's say I have an Android application called XYZ. That application supports importing a file with a custom extension like `file.xyz`.

Now what I want is to list my application in the "open with" apps dropdown when I try to open the `file.xyz` through the file manager or directly open my app & import it.

Something like this question [How to open app from a link without asking user to decide between browser or app, just open my app immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359781/how-to-open-app-from-a-link-without-asking-user-to-decide-between-browser-or-app)

Comment: The linked question is on URLs, not on files. This question may be better suited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension

Comment: Will that be the same for react native apps? If not let me know I will update the question.

Comment: Intent-filter elements in `AndroidManifest.xml` are processed by the Android OS itself, thus the used programming language doesn't matter.

Comment: But might be a limitation on expo apps because we don't have direct access to manifest with managed workflow.

Comment: Sorry but using that platform is your choice. There is one way to do it easy and one way to do it right. If you want to develop a complex app I would recommend using a real development platform.